# Screenshots of Allure Report not shown in jenkins, Only text attachments are shown

Tags: testing, jenkins-plugins, allure

I have downloaded the testng example from https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example.
I installed the Allure plugin on jenkins and ran the code. But in defects only txt attachmemts are shown and no .png attachments i.e. no screenshots are seen in the attachments.

However, When I am running the script on local, the screenshots are generated and placed in folder allure-results correctly. But The same are not visible on jenkins???

What can be the possible reasons for it??? Thanks for any help in advance!!

Regards.

Comment: We need more clarifications about your environment. Please specify Java and Maven versions Jenkins is using and Allure plugin version you're using with Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

In first , check if screenshots exists and paste code which takes screenshots.
Possible reason I have met was following

- Incompatible Allure version with gradle
- Not correctly set envirment variable , report directory etc...